# How to get Jstorm get tuplelifecycle time

Tags: apache-storm, jstorm

My question:I want to monitor the duration of each data in storm. How should I do?Are there any demos?I can only count the duration of each bolt processing.

Answer (score 0):

In both apache-storm and jstorm, you can get data of the monitor, and export that to whereever you want.

In storm, use Metrics Consumer (see http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/Metrics.html).

And in jstorm, use metrics uploader (see http://jstorm.io/Maintenance/JStormMetrics.html)

And there is a jstorm metricsUploader example here: https://github.com/lcy362/StormTrooper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/trooper/storm/monitor/MetricUploaderTest.java